# Is there a way to retrieve the index of an item stored within C#s' OrderedDictionary DS in O(1)~ complexity

Tags: c#, time-complexity, ordereddictionary

In other words - how do I get it without iterating over "GetEnumerator()"s value (O(n))?

for example, lets say I've created the following ordered dictionary (named aOrdDict), which contains the following pairs:

```
   INDEX      KEY                       VALUE
   0          testKey1                  testValue1
   1          testKey2                  testValue2
   2          keyToDelete               valueToDelete
   3          testKey3                  testValue3
```

how do i reveal that "testKey3"s' index within aOrdDict.GetEnumerator() is 3, without performing some procedure of the following sort:

```
int i = 0;
var ListedPairs = aOrdDict.GetEnumerator();
string wantedKey = "testKey3";

for(; i < aOrdDict.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    if (ListedPairs.key == wantedKey)
        break;
    listedPairs.MoveNext();
}
```

---

#### EDIT - Temporary Solution & Some Context

---

a little elaboration about the scenery that has led to my question, accompanied by a temporary solution I've implemented, (which is similar to what Martin Liversage suggested at the comments) :

I basically work on some bi-directional client<->server mediator.
after a server-->client message enters the mediator & processed,
upon feeding it forward to the client, both it's body & the DateTime.Now() value (down to ms) taken that moment
should be stored at the mediator in asociation to one another, get packed, and then sent to the client.

later on, the client sends requests to the server, each marked by a specific time-stamp.

it expects to receive some span of stored values which are adjacent & chronologically prior
to the input time stamp. at that stage, the ordered Dictionary was supposed to come in handy
by allowing me to address the value that was stored at 'timeStamp' by key  (hence - the need for a dict), then iterate
backwards, value by value, at the opposite order to that in which they were inserted. (hence - the need for a List)

eventually - I used a :

```
ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> aIndicesDict
```

for a {timeStamp, index} couple, and a

```
List<Tuple<string, someObject>> aSomeObjectsList
```

for a (timestamp, messageBody) couple,

storing the incoming values within both collections every time a new message
is sent from the server to the client.

then, upon an incoming request from the client to the server, we get the index related to the input timeStamp (from aIndicesDict - O(1)), allowing us to start iterating backwards from the relevant index of the list of tuples (within aSomeObjectsList - O(1) to get straight to the relevant List Entry).

as I wrote in the comments - I would still like to find a bit more efficient solution (memory wise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderedDictionary` does not provide the functionality that you want. Internally, there is no mapping from key to index. Instead you can map from either key or index to the actual value.

You can build you own ordered dictionary where you internally keep a list and an array: The list maps from index to key and the dictionary maps from key to value. This will provide a way to get the index from the key in O(1) but reading a value by index (and iterating in sequence) would be more costly because of the extra indirection. If you build your own collection you can also use generics which the ancient `OrderedDictionary` doesn't do.

However, why do you need to get the index from the key? If you use keys to lookup values and the index really is an ordering then you can perhaps include the "index" (really, the order) in the value?

Comment: yes, I've actually used the approach you've suggested as a temporary one. but might as well keep it, seeing that  it is what you've naturally recommended. would still have loved it if there was a lower memory complexity approach though.

I'll add it to my post and would let the question resonate a little more, just in case. but thank you for your thorough walk through :) .

as for your question,I'll add a thorough explanation of the task/environment at hand on the original post.